# Oracle/PL SQL curosr%notfound equivalent in Teradata

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, cursor, teradata

what is the equivalent of Oracle's `CURSOR%NOTFOUND` found in Teradata?

If not, then how can I translate below code to run in Teradata.

```
OPEN OPEN_CUR1;
   LOOP
      FETCH OPEN_CUR1 INTO ... some variables ...;
      EXIT WHEN OPEN_CUR1%NOTFOUND;
CLOSE OPEN_CUR1;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For detailed information about the CURSOR handling/behaviour in Teradata see page 47 in http://www.info.teradata.com/do_redirect.cfm?itemid=062280010

Basically the equivalent to `OPEN_CUR1%NOTFOUND` from Oracle in Teradata is that `SQLSTATE` is set to `7362` and the `SQLCODE` to `'02000'`... for handling this you can check pages 49, 76, 192-198, 405 ff. of the above document.

**EDIT - as per comment:**

From the example on page 49

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp1 (OUT par1 CHARACTER(50))
BEGIN
DECLARE var1 INTEGER;
DECLARE projcursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT projid, projectdesc
FROM project;
OPEN projcursor;
WHILE (SQLCODE = 0)
FETCH projcursor INTO var1, par1;
END WHILE;
FETCH projcursor INTO var1, par1;
CLOSE projcursor;
END;
```

They use `WHILE (SQLCODE = 0)` which means basically "while everything is fine and data is available".

Comment: Thanks for you prompt response and sharing the documentation. I have already gone through the documentation, but I wanted a precise example that what can replace cursor not found. Is there any SQLState that will suffice ?

Comment: see my EDIT above... I still strongly recommend to read the parts about SQLSTATE HANDLERs etc.